# How can check if token is a scam with web3js?

Tags: web3js, tokens, bsc, airdrop, bscscan

I build a small dApp for checking asset in my wallet.

I use Moralis API for get all token balance in my wallet (and it's work fine!).

But now, I would like to check if each token in my wallet is a "valid" token.

I mean if it's not a scam token or if it's not a fake airdrop scam token ?

What's for you the better way to do this with web3.js ? (Or something else maybe ?)

(I already try with a lot of things but nones works...)

Comment: define a scam token? IMO all tokens are scam

Comment: lol exactly ! But I mean a honeypot for example or like I already said a fake airdrop scam ?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean if it's not a scam token or if it's not a fake airdrop scam token ?

This is not possible with on-chain information only. Thus, there is no way to check with web3.js if a project is a scam or not. You need to check project-by-project basis if the project satisfies the criteria of a high quality project.

But generally the rule of a thumb is

- If you received any token to your wallet which you did not buy or subscribe for, it's a scam, because there is no point for anyone to send anything else besides scams

-> Everything in your wallet is a scam, unless you know otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can `simulate` the transactions on a main-net fork and check whether the transaction is doing what what's its supposed to.

You can use this to simulate: https://www.dark.florist/